# Lubuntu 14.04 on Dell Latitude D600 WiFi

Tags: 14.04, wireless, networking, drivers, lubuntu

I just recently installed lubuntu 14.04 LTS on my Dell Latitude D600. I had to forcepae in order for it to install. Once installed, I cannot get the WiFi driver to work. First, I plugged it into Ethernet and tried to install the driver with the Additional Drivers window. It looked like it worked then, once it rebooted, the driver wouldn't show up nor any wireless networks. The Additional Drivers window doesn't show it either. So, I googled it and tried with the tutorials [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1621331) and [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2239043) with no luck. I need the WiFi to work because I'm not going to be using it within Ethernet reach.

Also, this is what comes up in

```
$ lspci -nn | grep 0280
02:03.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4306 802.11b/g Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:4320] (rev02)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Comment: Well I tried the first one and it did nothing so I tried the second one.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I got it working by purging `linux-firmware-nonfree` for some reason.